# sp_blitz shows "Last good DBCC CHECKDB over 2 weeks old"

Tags: sql-server, dbcc, sp-blitz

When I run `sp_blitz`, I see

```
-[ RECORD 5 ]-------------------------
Priority          | 1
FindingsGroup     | Reliability
Finding           | Last good DBCC CHECKDB over 2 weeks old
DatabaseName      | model
URL               | https://BrentOzar.com/go/checkdb
Details           | Last successful CHECKDB:  never.
QueryPlan         | NULL
QueryPlanFiltered | NULL
CheckID           | 68
-[ RECORD 6 ]-------------------------
Priority          | 1
FindingsGroup     | Reliability
Finding           | Last good DBCC CHECKDB over 2 weeks old
DatabaseName      | msdb
URL               | https://BrentOzar.com/go/checkdb
Details           | Last successful CHECKDB:  never.
QueryPlan         | NULL
QueryPlanFiltered | NULL
CheckID           | 68
```

However, I just ran `DBCC CHECKDB`.

Comment: I had a similar problem when the database was in ReadOnly mode. The field on the database can't be updated so SP_Blitz reports that the last checkdb was a long time ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DatabaseName` is different in the output there. You have to run [`DBCC CHECKDB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql) for each database.

```
DBCC CHECKDB (model);
DBCC CHECKDB (msdb);
DBCC CHECKDB (master);
```

By default, [`DBCC CHECKDB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql) runs on the current database. If you connected without specifying a database, you're likely connected to the default database for your user. You can see your current database with

```
SELECT DB_NAME();
```

You can see all of your users' default databases with,

```
SELECT name, default_database_name FROM sys.server_principals;
```

You don't have to explicitly run it against the Resource Database, [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql)

> However, when `DBCC CHECKDB` is executed against the `master` database, a second CHECKDB is also run internally on the Resource database.